# UISlider iOS thumb repeats

Tags: ios, ios5, uislider

Currently my UISlider's thumb is repeating. Check this image out : http://d.pr/JT8H

This is all I'm doing :

`UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 330, 240,0)];
    [self.view addSubview:slider];`

Comment: My first guess is the `UISlider` is added multiple times. Can you please tell us more where this code is located?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have

```
 [self.view addSubview:slider];
```

down twice somewhere? I'd also make my slider at least 25px tall, you have it down as 0, I don't think that'd cause your problem though..